# Mule:Extracting parent flow message in subflow/synchronous flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Is there a way in mule to extract parent flow message in sub/synchronous flow after sub message source has generated its message and modify it.Sub flow is having its own message source.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the message of parent flow in sub flow ..
Now extracting a message depends on its data type ...

For example if the payload type is xml and you need to extract particular value of a node, you can use XPATH...
Similarly for JSON payload there is different techniques of extracting it..

And now if you want the entire payload of parent flow and not just part of it, then you can always use `#[message.payload]` expression in subflow